# xaringan slide separator not separating slides

Tags: r, xaringan

In this example `xaringan` presentation, why are both the `## blank page` and the `leaflet` map on the same slide, given I've separated them by the new-slide separator `---` ?

````
---
title: "map test"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default"]
    nature:
      highlightLines: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


## blank page

content 

--- 

leaflet page

```{r}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles()

```

---
````

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you've got an unintended space after the new slide separator after blank content as "--- ". Remove that space and it'll be recognized as real slide separator:

````
---
title: "map test"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default"]
    nature:
      highlightLines: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


## blank page

content 

---

leaflet page

```{r}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles()

```

---
````

Comment: It's at times like these you just have to laugh... Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I believe there's an RStudio option to strip trailing whitespace upon save? Anyway I've filed [this issue](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/151)

Comment: @MichaelChirico - so there is : Tools > Global Options > Code > Saving > 'strip trailing horizontal whitespace when saving'

Comment: This also applies to incremental slides - remove trailing spaces after `--`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm adding mathjax/latex equations and I had:

```
$$
\begin{aligned} P(Y= k)=\comb{k-1}{r-1} * p^r q^{k-r}, \qquad k= r,r+1
\end{aligned}\label{pascal}\tag{5}
$$
```

And I had to remove the breaklines

```
$$\begin{aligned} P(Y= k)=\comb{k-1}{r-1} * p^r q^{k-r}, \qquad k= r,r+1
\end{aligned}\label{pascal}\tag{5}$$
```

and then it worked. I've that it renders mathjax better if all the code is in a single line.