# incremental slides in xaringan package fails in long list

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan, remarkjs

I'm trying to make a incremental list with the `xaringan` package, however a bunch of bullet appears all together. Here is the visual example:

[image]

In this example, when I click once, element 1 appears like planned.  When I click the second time, both element 2 and 3 and the  `--` appears. Then I click a third time to have the 4th element appears.

This is the code I used:

```
---
title: "Incremental Slides with xaringan / remark.js"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2017/08/31"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---



# test 1
Two dash incremental fails in long list    
a simple list

--

- element 1 works

--

- element 2 triggers element 3

-- 

- element 3 appears too early

--

- element 4


---
```

It's actually really basic and I don't understand why it's failing.  At first I thought it was linked with hierarchical bullets:

```
- el1

--

- el2

--

- el3
  - ela

--

- el4
```

As my problem seems to appears only in those cases.  However, I've tried again with another brand new example:

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, Inc."
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---



blabla

- a

--

- b

--

- c

-- 

- d
```

which also gave me the wrong output:

[image]

Did I miss something?  Is it my setup or other people can reproduce the problem?

I have Rstudio version : 1.2.1335

and my session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 14393)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1  htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.5.1     xaringan_0.9.3  yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.1      rmarkdown_1.12  knitr_1.22      xfun_0.6       
[10] digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.13
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51120186/559676

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the bug.  The problem is linked with the trailing white spaces following the two dash (use `--` instead of `--_`).  Removing the  solve my problem.

It's quite sensitive...

Comment: FWIW, I was having trouble with vertical spacing between bullets; got it fixed by having a space before the `--` line but not after.