# Incremental does not work with $$ in xaringan

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

One of my xaringan slide has the following code, but incremental does not work properly with $$ equation $$. Wondering what do I miss here.

```
# Multiple regression


#### It is only when: 

$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x + u\;\; \text{with}\;\; x\perp u$$

-- 

#### Very strong with $non\text{-}experimental$ data.
```

This generates the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incremental slide is not working in your case, that's because you have used a space   after the two dash sign `--`. It's not related to `$$` sign.

Remove any space after `--` sign, then incremental slide will work.

---

This is actually a common error people face while working with xaringan incremental slides. [See this related answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120707/10858321) and this appreciation post from Yihui Xie (author of xaringan) about that answer, [Yue Jiang: A Ninja with Sharingan](https://yihui.org/en/2018/07/yue-jiang/)